# Get the key value from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following type of array:

```
Array (
  [2017-01-01] => Array (
    [booking_nb] => 0
  )
  [2017-01-02] => Array (
    [booking_nb] => 0
);
```

How can I get the value of `booking_nb` if the date is equal to `2017-01-02` ?

Do I need to loop into the array ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 2017-01-02 is an array key, you can do the following:

```
$array['2017-01-02']['booking_nb']; // will return the value 0
```

However, I recommend that if you are only storing the `booking_nb` value inside of each sub-array (i.e. no other elements inside the sub-arrays), you simply store them like so:

```
array(
  '2017-01-01' => 0,
  '2017-01-02' => 0,
)
```

This way, you can select with the following:

```
$array['2017-01-01']; // gives 0
```

The simplicity gained from this method also has the downside of the inability to store additional data, so use according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've just change the multidimensional array to an simple flat array.

Comment: @qatari My pleasure. As mentioned above, if you need to include additional data, simply change back to a multidimensional array. :)